# How to slow down the speed of execution?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium web-driver with testing. I want to slow down the speed of execution.
Here is the sample code:

```
@Parameters({ "provider_name", "branch", "address", "clientId", "website", "UserName", "Password", "Dpid" })
public void addDematAccount(String provider_name, String branch, String address, String clientId, String website,
        String UserName, String Password, String Dpid) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#/app/DematAccount/Add')]")).click();

    setParameter(provider_name, branch, address, clientId, website, UserName, Password, Dpid);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have used `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` and  `Thread.sleep(2000);` but not helping

Comment: But why do you want to slow down the speed of execution??? could you describe this??

Comment: it execute very fast so that i am not able to see the execution properly

Comment: You can debug to see the execution properly... thnaks

Comment: yeah, I'd like it to just slow down so I can watch it run.  Sometimes these pages zip past and I just need reassurance it's actually going through the steps I wrote.  So much easier than hauling out the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer any way to control the speed of each "step" in Selenium WebDriver. At one time, there was a setSpeed() method on the Options interface (in the Java bindings; other bindings had similar constructs on their appropriately-named objects), but it was deprecated long, long ago. The theory behind this is that you should not need to a priori slow down every single step of your WebDriver code. If you need to wait for something to happen in the application you're automating, you should be using an implicit or explicit wait routine.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation.. but sometimes the values of textbox1 is passed to the textbox2.. may be due to fast execution.. is there any solution for that..??

Comment: @disha, values intended for textbox1 gets passed to textbox2 has nothing to do with execution speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view it, and its too fast I would think you could maybe record your test being executed and then review it ?

See here : http://www.seleniummonster.com/boost-up-your-selenium-tests-with-video-recording-capability/

And here : http://unmesh.me/2012/01/13/recording-screencast-of-selenium-tests-in-java/

Here is some examples from the above link

```
public void startRecording() throws Exception
{
GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
this.screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc,
new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey,      ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,DepthKey, 24,       FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),QualityKey, 1.0f,KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 *   60),new Format(MediaTypeKey,MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",FrameRateKey,       Rational.valueOf(30)),null);
this.screenRecorder.start();
}
 public void stopRecording() throws Exception
{
this.screenRecorder.stop();
}
```

The whole purpose of automated tests ( in my opinion ) is so they can be run in the background without user interaction/without being viewed. Also, if you want to do as many tests as possible in a certain about of time speed and parallized testing is essential. If you want to view your tests being executed I think the above method would be good to ensure you don't ruin the performance of Selenium and view the execution when completed, you will have full control with the video to replay etc.

Comment: This answers my use case, which is doing a manual review of a test that is already written before we accept it into our body of regression tests.   However, it seems a lot less convenient than temporarily setting an option in Selenium WebDriver which simply says "run at 50% speed" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

serv_obj=Service("C:\Browserdrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)

driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/en")
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to execute your program slowly or even step by step, you can try the following approaches:

- execute your program in debug mode one step at a time;
- refactor your code into function blocks, only execute a block of code at one time, you will not see you code being executed slowly as in time, but it becomes easier for you to associate your codes with the results.

Comment: With respect to Selenium tests, this is not useful.  The tests fail under race conditions  that do not appear when debugging so it becomes nigh impossible to either deduce or debug the behavior without modifying execution pace.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny, good point. True. My answer was ill-considered.